# How to save multiple line from JTextArea to a File in Java

Tags: java, file, jtextarea

I'm making a simple notepad, which will save the content from JTextArea to a File. But i have a problem, i'm not able to save a multiline text.

Here's my code:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
File writeFile;
FileWriter fileWriter = null;
BufferedWriter bufWriter = null;

writeFile = new File("note.txt");
try {
    fileWriter = new FileWriter(writeFile);
    bufWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
    bufWriter.write(textArea.getText());
    bufWriter.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

For example, i have a button and a textarea. When I input something like this:

```
test line 1
test line 2
```

and press the button to save, the file created. but the contents of the file, become like this

```
test line 1test line 2
```

Please give me a detail answer, so i can understand properly. i'm new in java GUI.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Besides your JTextArea not containing any text, what is your problem? Please be more specific.

Comment: Not clear. But to have multiple lines you need to make JTextArea multiline. There is attribute you need to set to make this area multiline.

Comment: sorry, i put some example to this. i hope you guys can solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after trying your code, i see that your code only save the text in a single line. for example in the text area it's looked like this

first line 
second line 
third line

but in the file you just got

first linesecond linethird line

if that is the case you can use this code

```
    File writeFile;
    Writer writer = null;

    writeFile = new File("D:\\note.txt");
    try {
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(writeFile), "utf-8"));
        jTextArea1.write(writer);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // report
    } finally {
        try {
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {/*ignore*/
        }
    }
```

in this code we use writer from jtextarea itself, so it will save the text as we see at the jtextarea.

hope this help

Comment: it's work, thank you. but any chance to use FileWriter instead of OutputStreamWriter & FileOutputStream?

Comment: from a couple article that i have read, it is possible to do that by splitting the text based on number of character that exist in a single line in jtextarea, then manually add line for every line that exist. but so far this code is the simplest way that i have found